# Facebook iOS SDK - how to determine if user has deleted app without calling authorize each time?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm implementing the Facebook iOS SDK in my app as directed in the Facebook docs. Namely, access tokens and respective expiries are saved such that anytime my Facebook login routine is executed, it can check `isSessionValid` and if YES it avoids performing an extraneous `authorize` call.  This works great, except when the user has since deauthorized/deleted the Facebook app.

Because `isSessionValid` only checks if there's a saved access token and expiry is okay, it doesn't seem like there's any way to catch the case where the app was deauthorized and thus execute `authorize` again.

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Because my app maintains its own session and should keep users logged in indefinitely, the whole routine should only really happen once so the overhead of just forgetting about saving tokens/expiries and running `authorize` each time might not be so bad. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

You can set only authorization with Safari or inside App authorization, to do this you have to edit Facebook.m file from:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

to:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

Comment: I'm aware of that - how does it help with this situation though? It's not the means of authorization that's the issue, but rather the fact that if we used saved tokens we have no way of checking whether or not the user since deleted/deauthorized the app through their Facebook profile.

Comment: Sory i didn't read it correctly, i'm not sure but there is no possible to check this through fb api, did you check when the fbDidNotLogin is fired or some of FbSession delegates? but you can have create server where you will have database of authorized users to your app and everytime user open your app you will be checking is token from user default is in server.